# Unknown Host Exception - Android

Tags: android, exception

I have a GET method which works fine when I try with Advanced rest Client. Im using HttpurlConnection to make the "GET" call. But I'm getting "unknown host Exception"

Comment: Can you detail a bit more the question? Can you add some of the code and talk about all the technologies involved?

Comment: problem with your internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

This error usually means the endpoint your trying to connect to doesn't exist.

From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that the IP address of a host could not be
>   determined.